# How to get last login details of GCP users

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform

I have a requirement to fetch list of users who did not login in to Google Console for the past 90 days. When researched found 2 ways of doing it

1. Using Reports API with Google workspace
2. Login audit log, but would need administrator access to achieve this.

Can anyone suggest any simpler option if available?

Comment: 1) What type of users? Gmail, Google Workspace, etc? 2) Users do not log into Google Cloud. They are already authenticated by Google Accounts, therefore Google Cloud does not store this information. 3) If your users are Workspace users, then you can use the admin APIs to extract information about user activity. 4) Logging is performed for certain actions but this does not indicate when they logged in, only when they performed something that is logged. 5) Admin rights are required as this information is considered sensitive and requires secure access.

Comment: 6) Google uses OAuth. OAuth allows token refresh which does not require logging in. Therefore, I can stay logged in for long periods of time. Your goal of tracking user login/logout is not realistic with today's authorization and authentication systems.

Comment: Seems shitty that GCP pretends to be just like gmail or google docs for user access. I, too, want to have the last access date/time of each user to each project, or at least specifically one project. I guess it is in keeping with the other shitty GCP stuff.